# Replace contiguous duplicates by a set value, but only if length of contiguous range more than a threshold

Tags: c#, arrays, list, duplicates, contiguous

What would be an efficient way to replace contiguous identical values in a list elements by another given value, but only if the the contiguous sequence runs for more than a certain number of elements (eg : more or equals to 5)

Example:

["red"; "red"; "blue"; "green"; "green"; **"red"; "red" ; "red"; "red"; "red"; "red";** "yellow"; "white"; "white"; "red"; "white"; "white"]

should become:

["red"; "red"; "blue"; "green"; "green"; **"ignore"; "ignore" ; "ignore"; "ignore"; "ignore"; "ignore";** "yellow"; "white"; "white"; "red"; "white"; "white"]

Any idea?

Comment: Do *you* have any idea?

Comment: *efficient way* is subjective, do you mean speed, memory, lines of code, readability? either way   *O(n)* `for` loop, with a first index, last value, and duplicate counter. When reaching a threshold it overwrites the given word up to current index and going forward. There is no need to over think this.. You could  get fancy with *Linq* however i think that would be less intuitive

Comment: MoreLinq's `GroupAdjacent` is one place you could start.

Comment: How about enumerating the list, keeping track of the previous value, as well as the index of the first identical value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, using [`GroupAdjacent`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.7/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_GroupAdjacent__2_1.htm) to group contiguous duplicates using the nuget package [`MoreLinq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) is an option:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "red", "red", "blue", "green", "green", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "yellow", "white", "white", "red", "white", "white" };

var result = strings
    .GroupAdjacent(x => x)
    .SelectMany(grp => (grp.Count() >= 5) ?
                grp.Select(x => "ignore") : 
                grp);

Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", result) + " }");
```

Result:

```
{ red, red, blue, green, green, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, yellow, white, white, red, white, white }
```

The above also uses [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) to flatten the grouped `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` sequence into a `IEnumerable<string>`, and then a ternary operator to decide if the group should be completely replaced by `"ignore"` with [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) if the group length from [`Enumerable.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8)is *greater or equal to 5*, or left as is.